# Finding smallest value greater 1 in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find the smallest Value > 1 in specific Cells (H25:H36) via VBA.
I tried it with following formula:

```
=MIN(IF(H25:H36<=1,"",H25:H36))
```

but an error message pops up, saying that this formula is not correct.

Does anyone know how I could solve this problem?

Comment: IF-Statement:
x;y;z
x = What to check
y = if true 
z = if false

Comment: So you want this in VBA or as a formula?

Comment: It would be better in VBA but you also can add formulas via vba in cells

Comment: I know. But the formula you provided is a worksheet formula and not a VBA solution.

Comment: Okay the solutions listed with formulas are definitly not working, the reason might me that im using a german version (? , I also use the german words for the commands).

Is there a vba way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

```
=MIN(IF(H25:H36>1,H25:H36))
```

Entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

VBA (sort of):

```
MsgBox Activesheet.Evaluate("=MIN(IF(H25:H36>1,H25:H36))")
```

Comment: also pops out an error message. And in cell where this formula is it says #Name?

Comment: Yes I mean 1 - was testing with 3

Comment: Dim SmallestValue As String

SmallestValue = 999999999

For x = 25 To 36


    If Cells(x, 8).Value > 1 And Cells(x, 8).Value < SmallestValue And Cells(x, 8) <> "" Then
        SmallestValue = Cells(x, 8).Value
        
    End If

Next x

MsgBox SmallestValue